# check if value is higher in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Right now i have this code:

```
keys = {
    'key1':[5],
    'key2':[2],
    'key3':[3],
    'key4':[2],
    'key5':[1],
    'key6':[2],
    'key7':[9],
    'key8':[10],
    'key9':[8],
}


for i in keys:
     print(keys[i])
```

the last prints all the values from the list
what i want to do is only print the key and the value if the value is bigger than 5

i cant just do

```
if keys[i] > 5:
```

that doesnt work

so does anybody know how i can check and write the key and value if the value is higher than 5?

Comment: `if keys[i][0] > 5` since your value is a list not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the values are arrays and not numbers. When working with an array you will need to specify the index for the value you want. In your case all your arrays only have one value, so the index you want each time is `0`.

You can do this to check the *first* item in the array, it will also print the key:

```
for i in keys:
    if keys[i][0] > 5:
        print(i, keys[i])
```

[Here is a working example](https://repl.it/KnWQ)

---

Of course it depends what you actually want to print. If you want to print the whole array:

```
print(i, keys[i])
```

If you want to print just the first value in the array:

```
print(i, keys[i][0])
```

Personally you should review what you actually want to work with, if your values are only ever going to be single integers, then you shouldn't really be using arrays at all and should define the collection differently:

```
keys = {
    'key1':5
}
```

Comment: Thansk but how do i thatn print the corresponing key to it

for example from code in OP key8 10

Answer (score 0):

keys[i] is returning a list of numbers, not a single number. Either change your declaration to an int:

```
keys = {
    'key1':5...
```

or change the line that compares it to pick the **first** entry in the 'keys' list:

```
if keys[i][0] > 5:
```

if you wanted to print the key name and it's value if this returns true, you would use:

```
if keys[i][0] > 5:
    print i, keys[i][0]
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i thatn print the corresponing key to it for example from code in OP key8 10